# Rexx to split a file based on date column

Tags: mainframe, rexx

I want to Split my Input file based on Date Column, My input file will have multiple dates. I want to split the file based on No of dates in input. 
Like I have 5 different dates in input file then I should get 5 output files. 
The output file names should be same as the input date.

like my input data is like :

201607131000
201607131500
201607142000
201607142500

then based on [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3muOq.jpg)date in first 8 columns I should have 2 output files.

This image is my current code, my problem is data from previous stem file is repeating in next stem file.

Lets say I have 3 records with date 20160712 and 2 records 20160713...then my both output files are having 3 records each. the 3rd record from out1 is repeated in out2.

Comment: Please copy/paste your code, using your emulator, into the question by use of the edit link under the question. No-one's going to look at code as an image taken by phone, even without the ghost on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a nested loop to allocate the datasets.

```
/*
INPUT:
201607131000 201607131500 201607142000 201607142500 
*/


/* REXX EXEC */                                                         
input1 = USER.PAULWILL.INPUT                                          
output_dataset = USER.PAULWILL.TEST2016                                   
"ALLOC F(INFILE) DSN('"INPUT1"') SHR REUSE"                             
"EXECIO * DISKR INFILE(FINIS STEM RECD."                                
"FREE F(INFILE)"                                                        

Call MOVE_DATE recd.0 output_dataset    /* pass number of dates, output dsn format */                                

MOVE_DATE:                                                              
arg rec_count dsname                                                    
do i = 1 to recd.0                                                      
  DateCount = WORDS(recd.i)                                             
  say 'DateCount:'DateCount                                             
  do j = 1 to DateCount                                                                 
    dnum = SUBSTR(WORD(recd.i,j),5,6)                                     
    "ALLOC DA('"dsname'.PT'dnum"')                          /* allocate new dataset */
    NEW DIR(0) SPACE(10,10) DSORG(ps)                                   
      RECFM(f,b) LRECL(1000) BLKSIZE(0)"                             
    "ALLOC DA('"dsname'.PT'dnum"') FI(OFILE) SHR REUSE"     
    QUEUE dnum                                             /* write some input in */                       
    "EXECIO * DISKW OFILE (FINIS"                                       
    "FREE F(OFILE)"                                                     
  end                                                                   
end /* do */                                                            


/*
OUTPUT:
USER.PAULWILL.TEST2016.PT071310 
USER.PAULWILL.TEST2016.PT071315 
USER.PAULWILL.TEST2016.PT071420 
USER.PAULWILL.TEST2016.PT071425 
*/
```

Things to consider:

1. The Middle Level Qualifier (MLQ) dataset in this example had to be
   allocated ahead of time.

   ```
   USER.PAULWILL.TEST2016
   ```
2. Remember [naming rules for datasets](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.ikjc200/ikj2o20038.htm), that's why I used 'PT[date]'
3. There's no logic here in the event the dataset already exists.

[Bill Woodger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1927206/bill-woodger) is correct ...take the time to type the code rather than taking a bad screenshot.